# Load form object on fetching from ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form that renders partial 'form'.

```
= form_for(@booking, :as => :booking, :url => admin_bookings_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  = render partial: "form", locals: { f: f }
```

Inside the partial form again another partial is rendered based on new_record?.

```
- if f.object.new_record?
  #extra-products
    = render partial: 'new_booking_extra_product', locals: { f: f }
- else
  = render partial: 'extra_product', locals: { f: f }
```

In bookings#new, when the user selects particular car_id, I want to show associated products with it through ajax. For that I have used ajax to make a request to bookings#fetch_extra_product.

```
# Ajax request to fetch product
$('#booking_car_id').on('change', function(e){
    var selectedCarId = $("#booking_car_id option:selected").val();
    var url = "/admin/bookings/" + selectedCarId + "/fetch_extra_product";

    $.ajax(url,{
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(msg){
      },
      error: function(msg) {
        console.log("Error!!!");
      }
    });
  });

# Bookings#fetch_extra_product
def fetch_extra_product
    @car_id = params[:car_id] || Car.all.order('id desc').first.id
    @extra_product = Car.find(@car_id).extra_products

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

The fetch_extra_product.js.erb looks as follow:

```
$('#extra-products').html('$("<%= j render(:partial => 'new_booking_extra_product', :locals => {:f => f}) %>")');
```

But the form object (f) is undefined on this state. What's the best way to fetch the object or the best way to get through this problem?

Comment: Can you update the question with `_new_booking_extra_product.html.erb code`?

Comment: It's undefined cause you are doing an ajax request from the client side. The 'f' object exists only on server side during the first request.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to render a partial view with the associated products server-side when the Ajax request is received. Then you can send the HTML from that partial as part of your response and use the Ajax `success` callback to attach the partial view to the DOM however you want it. Then you can have (in your controller) code something like this:

```
def fetch_extra_product

  # Unless you're using @car_id in a view or something, I'd just
  # just use a local variable instead of an instance variable
  #
  car_id = params[:car_id] || Car.all.order('id desc').first.id
  @extra_products = Car.find(car_id).extra_products

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render partial: 'extra_products_div', status: :ok }
  end
```

Then your partial code is something like this:

```
<div class="extra-products">
  <% @extra_products.each do |product| %>
    <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
    ...
  <% end %>
</div>
```

That way, your JavaScript can then go along the lines of:

```
$.ajax(url, {
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#foo').attach(msg);
  },
  error: function(msg) {
    console.log('Error!!!');
  }
});
```

One other comment: If your API is only going to get a request to this route via Ajax, you don't need the `respond_to` block. In that case you can just put the `render partial: 'extra_products_div', status: :ok` under the line where you
define `@extra_products`.